# Data store return only one record in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to view user list in a template.But it retrieves only one(last) record i have entered.Why is it returning a single record? Is it a data-store cache problem?Following is the approach that i have followed

templates/userlist.hbs

```
{{#each item in model}}
{{#link-to 'userlist.edit' item.id}}edit:{{item.userName}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

routes/userlist.js

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
      }

    });
```

model/user.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({


    docType:DS.attr('string'),
    firstName:DS.attr('string'),
    role:DS.attr('string'),


    userName:DS.attr('string'),
    password:DS.attr('string'),

    lastName:DS.attr('string'),
    mobileNo:DS.attr('string'),
    landNo:DS.attr('string'),
    address:DS.attr(
        {
        no:'string',
        street:'string',
        city:'string'
    }
    ),

    nicNo:DS.attr('string'),



});
```

api/user.js

```
module.exports.getAllUsers=function(req,res) {
    UserModel.find({},function(err,docs) {
        if(err) {
            res.send({error:err});
        }
        else {
            res.send({user:docs});
        }
    });
};
```

app/routes.js

```
router.route('/api/users').get(function(req,res){users.getAllUsers(req,res)})
                              .post(function(req,res){console.log(req.body);users.addUser(req,res);});
```

Comment: You need to show example response from your API to `this.store.find('user');` call.

Comment: Also, what versions of Ember and Ember Data do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to name key for returned data `users`, instead of `user`.

So, in `getAllUsers` function body change:

```
res.send({ user: docs });
```

To:

```
res.send({ users: docs });
```